# Search by name in ASP.NET Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity for Authorization, In the Role Table, I have roles like : '**Role 1**','**Role 2**','**Role 3**','**Role 4**','**Role 5**','**Role n**'. It can be any numbers.

My requirement is that user having any of the role will be able to access the page.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Role 1", "Role 2")] // In this example, Number of roles 
//are known. But in my case, number of roles is not known.
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Is there any way I can search for keyword `"Role"` only? Like SQL `"%Role%"` query.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, you want allow access to all roles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute` does not have this feature, but you can derive a class from it and implement it yourself.

You can use this code

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string RolePattern { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
        string[] roles = claimsIdentity.FindAll(claimsIdentity.RoleClaimType).Select(claim => claim.Value).ToArray();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RolePattern) && !roles.Any(role => Regex.IsMatch(role, RolePattern)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And Add `CustomAuthorize` on your action

```
[CustomAuthorize(RolePattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*Role[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")] 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way. If you want to authorize this Action with any role, you can just use `[Authorize]` without specifying the roles.

Another way is to create a static class with the roles as constants.

For example:

```
public static class RoleConstants
{
     public const string RoleOne = "Role 1";
     /////the other roles here
}
```

And outside of this class or even inside the class, you can define a static string to include the roles you want to use in the **Authorize** attribute:

```
public static string ALLROLES = RoleOne + "," + //other roles;
```

And in your `[Authorize]` attribute you can use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleConstants.ALLROLES)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

But in your situation, I would recommend you to use my first example. Just the `[Authorize]` attribute without specifying the roles.